# CSS Columns: box-shadow is rendered faulty on Google Chrome (Masonry Layout)

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome, layout

I want to create a masonry layout with CSS Columns. Each item has a box-shadow and a random height (in the following CodePen I simulated this with exact heights).

And there's the problem: The box-shadows are appended to the wrong column if the elements use different heights. I would even say that this is a rendering issue in Google Chrome?

Do you have any idea, how to solve this issue in context of the idea to have a masonry layout?

https://codepen.io/malte94/pen/yLomKJe

[image]

```css
.box {
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  min-height: 200px;
  margin: 10px;
}

.columns {
  display: block;
  column-count: 3;
  page-break-inside: avoid;
  break-inside: avoid;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.columns * {
  display: block;
  max-width: 100%;
  page-break-inside: avoid;
  break-inside: avoid;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="columns">
  <div class="box" style="height: 200px;"> Hey there! </div>
  <div class="box" style="height: 400px;"> Hey there! </div>
  <div class="box" style="height: 500px;"> Hey there! I'm broken </div>
  <div class="box" style="height: 100px;"> Hey there! </div>
  <div class="box" style="height: 50px;"> Hey there! </div>
  <div class="box" style="height: 250px;"> Hey there! </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Could not reproduce. The box shadows look like fine to me, and consistent with Firefox.

Comment: I really didn't understand the problem so if you could clarify

Comment: It's only on Google Chrome apparently ...